# Allow user to upload favicon without any caching issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, browser-cache, favicon

In my react application, I allow users to customise favicon. They can add their own favicon through application interface itself. I want to avoid the favicon caching problem.
What is the best way to do that ?

Some approaches I can think of :

1. Adding Date.now() in the href.

> link rel="icon" type="image/png"
> href="fs/d/favicon/favicon_32x32.png?v=<%= Date.now() %>"
> data-favicon-file="fs/d/favicon/favicon_32x32.png?v=<%= Date.now() %>" sizes="32x32" />

But here I feel Date.now() will give me a new value each time and hence every time it will send a request to server for fetching favicon.

2. Another approach i'm thinking of doing it via some webpack plugin to add hash with the favicon image. But i'm not sure would it work with users uploading their own favicon. And if possible, I'm not sure which plugin to use.

Could anyone please help here.
Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just change the filename to a random string during upload?

Comment: Would that work with CDN. Having a different filename during upload ?